# Using Kinect camera with two applications at once

Tags: wpf, camera, kinect, skype, kinect-sdk

I'm trying to create a WPF application that makes a Skype video call with the use of Kinect gestures (Kinect SDK v2.0). I want to use the Kinect color camera in the video call, while still be able to use Kinect in my WPF application to detect the "hung up" gesture. Is there a way to do this? While the Skype video call is active, I don't really need Kinects color stream in my WPF application. I just need the Body stream to detect the gestures. I'm using the Kinect for Xbox One.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. It works out of the box like that.
The SDK 2.0 is designed specifically to enable "simultaneous multi-app support":

> Improved multi-app support enables multiple applications to access a
>   single sensor simultaneously. - [Developing with Kinect: Simultaneous multi-app support (on the very bottom)](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/kinect/develop)

There isn't anything special you have to consider. Since the SDK doesn't allow you to change any camera settings (like exposure time or gain), your applications basically just have read-access to the SDK, so they can't interfere with each other.

Just develop you applications separately and run them at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to add that I had to use this: [link](http://codingbytodesign.net/2014/07/20/kinectcamv2-for-kinect-v2/) to make Kinect work with Skype and than both Skype (in video call) and the WPF application were able to use Kinect at the same time.

Comment: Latest Kinect runtimes drivers should allow you to use the RGB camera from kinect v2 as a regular camera, as mentioned before you will be stuck on default resolution but should be detected on windows with any software.